# What data structure should I use to index geographic coordinates?

Tags: data-structures, geospatial

I have a set of objects that have latitude and longitude coordinates and I need to be able to match another set to the closest item. Simple nearest-neighbor stuff. My best thought is to convert the lat/lng coordinates to 3D coordinates and then store in either a K-d tree or an octree for later lookup. It should work and be good enough for all practical purposes (see: [kdtree for geospatial point search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933807/kdtree-for-geospatial-point-search)), but something about this feels off. I think it's the part where it's really just a 2D manifold in 3D space.

Is there a more appropriate structure to use or am I simply overthinking this?

Comment: I don't understand why you are thinking of converting lat/long to 3D coordinates before storing in either structure.  Surely their 2D equivalents would suffice ?

Comment: Two problems: 1. Distance between lines of longitude compresses at higher latitudes, distorting distance along one axis. 2. Lines can't cross a seam in the coordinate system and so could be considered much further apart than they really are. e.g. Two points on either side of 180 degrees longitude would be considered maximally far apart on that axis, despite actually being near.

Comment: In that case start with a *geodesic grid* and build your data structure from that.  But (a) I suspect the complications of doing that will be greater than dealing with the problems you outline using structures originally intended for planar application, and (b) I presume from your comment that your points are, essentially, randomly distributed across the face of the Earth, that they are not, as points representing (for example) railway stations would not be - none of those occur in high latitudes.

Answer (score 0):

Even Wikipedia says:

> a k-d tree (short for k-dimensional tree) is a space-partitioning data structure for organizing points in a **k-dimensional** space.

so go ahead and use your 2D points (*without* projecting them to 3D, or something similar).

Insert them into the tree, and then query the tree in logarithmic time - and there, all happy!

Comment: Unfortunately, that has flaws. See the comments on the question for details.